# Is $\max\limits_{x \in [0,1]} |x-c| x(1-x)$ minimal if and only if $c=0.5$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is the following statement true?
$$\max_{x \in [0,1]} |x-c| x(1-x) \text{ is minimal } \Leftrightarrow \max_{x \in [0,1]} |x-c|\text{ is minimal } \Leftrightarrow c=0.5$$

This question arises in some calculations related to an optimization problem. I reduced it to what is relevant. The second equivalence is clear, but I am not sure about the first one.

Comment: Do not delete your question.

Comment: I did not downvote you, and I don't know who did, but typically no one minds if a question is "silly". They just want you to include some information about what you know or have tried on the problem.

Comment: The question seems fine, though the point of this site is to keep both questions and answers, not to delete them. Anyway other then that it would be helpful if you could include some information as to why did you consider this question, was this problem given to you? Also ideally how did you arrive at $c=0.5$, such information helps us write answers which match your experience level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Critical Value Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300720/critical-value-problem)

Answer (score 1):

We have to study the function
$$f_c(x):=(x-c)x(1-x)$$
on the $x$-interval $[0,1]$. Its graph is a cubical parabola with three real zeros $c$, $0$, $1$,  and highest coefficient $<0$. It follows that $f$ has  a local minimum and to the right of it a local maximum. Due to symmetry we may assume $c\leq{1\over2}$.

If $c<0$ the local minimum of $f_c$ is between $c$ and $0$, and the local maximum at $g(c)\in\ ]0,1[\ $, whereby $g(c)$ is the righthand zero of $f_c'$, hence
$$g(c)={1\over3}\bigl(1+c+\sqrt{1-c+c^2}\bigr)\ .$$
The value $f\bigl(g(c)\bigr)$ is then also the maximum of $|f_c|$ on $[0,1]$.

If $0<c\leq{1\over2}$ the local minimum of $f_c$ is between $0$ and $c$, and the local maximum of $f_c$ is between $c$ and $1$, whereby the upward bump of $f_c$ is higher than the downward bump, since $c\leq{1\over2}$. It follows that again the maximum of $|f_c|$ on $[0,1]$ is at $g(c)$.

It remains to study the function
$$\psi(c):=f_c\bigl(g(c)\bigr)\qquad\left(-\infty<c\leq{1\over2}\right)\ .$$
Unfortunately no simple expression for $\psi$ results. But we can show that  $\psi$ is decreasing, hence minimal at $c={1\over2}$.

*Proof.* Write$$F(x,c):=f_c(x)=(x-c)x(1-x)\ .$$
Then $\psi(c)=F\bigl(g(c),c\bigr)$, and therefore
$$\eqalign{\psi'(c)&=F_{.1}\bigl(g(c),c\bigr)g'(c)+F_{.2}\bigl(g(c),c\bigr)\cr  &=0+\bigl(-x(1-x)\bigr)_{x=g(c)}\cr  &=-g(c)\bigl(1-g(c)\bigr)<0\ .\qquad\square\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\hat{c}= \text{arg minimal}_c\{ \max_{x\in [0,1]} |x-c|x(1-x) \} \leq \text{arg minimal}_c\{ \max_{x\in [0,1]} [\frac{|x-c|+x+1-x}{3}]^3 \}(\text{Using AM-GM inequality)} = \text{arg minimal}_c\{ \max_{x\in [0,1]} [\frac{|x-c|+1}{3}]^3 \}\Leftrightarrow \text{arg minimal}_c\{ \max_{x\in [0,1]} |x-c| \} (\text{since} [|x-c|+1]^3 \text{is symmetric about $c$} )=0.5 $$

I think this is what you wanted.